# How to check if Android device is an STB

Tags: android

I want to know a way on how to know if my `android device` is an `stb(set top box)`, been looking at the internet and stuff in in overflow but couldnt find the answer.

Comment: Please only use the code-formatting backticks for actual code. Try bold/italic instead.

Comment: What is your criteria for "if [your] android device is an stb(set top box)"? Is it that it is connected to a television? If so, what about phones and tablets that connect to televisions via HDMI, MHL, Miracast, etc.? Is it that it is not a touchscreen device? Is it something else?

Comment: its the only thing connected..no tabs, no phones, and just wanted to know how to ID my stb from the TV so i'll know that it is an android stb.

Comment: I just want to check that wether the device is android stb or not on which my app is running.

Comment: If whoever makes your STB is anything like those I deal with, there probably isn't any way to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `android.hardware.type.television` feature descriptor:

> This feature defines "television" to be a typical living room
>   television experience: displayed on a big screen, where the user is
>   sitting far away and the dominant form of input is something like a
>   d-pad, and generally not through touch or a mouse/pointer-device.

You can check its value in the following way:

```
public static boolean isAndroidTV(Context context) {
     final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
     return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEVISION);
}
```

Code source [here](http://intellectualcramps.wordpress.com/2013/09/13/detecting-television-feature-on-android/). Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html).

Comment: i ran the snippet on my android stb and it returned false. what should i do?

Comment: that sounds good too, how can i do that? coz the code you've provided still returns false.

Comment: @AceMunim: `android.hardware.type.television` appears to have been added in Android 4.1. If your environment is older than that, you will get `false`. Otherwise, contact the manufacturer of your box and ask them to fix their firmware.